# Video card temps too high?

Tags: video, graphics-card, computer-building, temperature

I have a XFX GT 240 1GB DDR5 video card with idle temps around 40C and load temps at 60C+.

Are these too high? Should I be concerned?

Comment: Removed Windows 7 tag because it's irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in the 60s you are probably okay with pretty much any modern piece of hardware that is in proper working order, and actually has active cooling (a fan as opposed to just fins).

This isn't exactly apples-to-oranges, but I have a Quadro 5000 across the room from me that costs the better part of $2K, and it's pulling 85­°C right now and I couldn't be less concerned.

Answer (score 1):

These temperatures are fine